# should i even look for my soulmate?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism

shalom everyone,

my question is complicated to say the least....and to be honest...even if i cant find an answer here...im hoping i can at least share a little my burden here

im a woman of 40 years old. from europe

when growing up i had no idea my maternal side is jewish. we went to church and i never could find the answers i needed there. from age 7 till 20 i went to church but i left. i had searched into all idol worship religions and came to the conclusion that its all lies and against Hashem. En the same with islam.

i had a strange connection and almost obsession with jews. curious about them. but where i live there were none growing up.

when i was 17 my parents and i went to israel for vacation...and that was for me emotionally and spiritually such a moment. it left a deep imprint in my soul.

7 years ago i learned from online the 613 mitzvot and i knew then: this is the "lawbook" that i had been trying to live by in a goyim world!!! i didnt understand why....but all i knew was that this IS IT. THE truth and how the world should be ...i didnt know at that time yet why i felt strongly connected to these laws.

i have two children from one man ...a non jew, that i had a relationship with many years ago. my kids are already teens.
I started delving in my family history.....i discovered some things about my maternal side...but wasnt sure. untill my oldest aunt confessed that my full maternal great great grandmother was a indianjewish woman. that intermarried with a muslim. she left him later.....migrated to south america and had their my great grandmother. who had my grandma (father goy) and she my mom...my dad is also a goy.

i have been trying to find any papers with more info....not just jewish but any info on my great grandma and great greatgrandma....but no proof of any religious background.

3 years ago i started literally begging the Av Beit Din here through letters to please let me convert.

my family broke most contact because i choose this path. and its highly antisemitic here. i hardly socialize at all with people here. i talk with them at work but i do kiruv a lot and am in contact with orthodox kiruv rabbanim from israel and usa.

but here....where live...there is a small community in the capital but they are very modern. much more to the liberal side. and all rabbanim ....including the av beit din are chabad. And its far away from here. thats the only jewish we have in all my country. but i registered 4 years ago for rental houses to move there and have been actively responding to houses but its in Hashem His hands if i can move

the chabad community here....and please dont take this as an insult...but are also highly "modern" so no teaching how crucial modesty is. no yichud.....no shomer negiah....dressed like full goyim.i took on modesty 3 years ago. fully covered. the women in my family always did this. i didnt sit and wait. i got a chumash,tanakh, siddur....etc etc mussar books. yalkut yosef...since my family is from india,central asia,west asia and middle east and levant. i connect very much with the teachings of the ben ish hai and some halacha of Rav Obadiah Yosef was very close to the very little the women in my family still kept. it was mixed with their heresy of islam but they for instant kept kashrut .......they had complete rest day on saturday...etc etc

i have been learning from shiurim of certified Rabbanim for years...

for 3 years i have been begging....literally begging the Beit Din here to please allow me to convert.....the first time i wrote and called for 1 year and 4 months to the sephardic rabbi to please at least have a talk with me so i could explain my reasons

i managed to have a meeting with the Av Beit Din and sephardic Rabbi.....they said after the talk that i would had to convert and that they would get back on what their decision would be.

for 5 months i waited and asked for a response. patiently waiting....the answer was no. i begged again for 6 months. again a no. "if my situation would change...then they would consider"

:(  i waited again ....for another six months i begged....calling,,,,writing....i cant just go up there...in my country there is much security at jewish places...without an appointment its useless.
then i got my third no.....i asked for a reason...but didnt get one. i wrote them my whole process...what i learned so far. what i already keep. i keep all basic mitzvot that im alllowed. kosher i have been living for years now. my whole kitchen i re did. but i cant dip my plates etc in a mikveh. but thats all that is missing. i say the daily blessings and beracha on food. i pray once a day. and say tehilim. i keep all days but i break them a little each time. so shabbat i keep 99%. and i mean it all. challah....i have a kashered blech and hotwater kettle from ohr leshabbat etc etc.....
another few months and asked again...no answer....then begged again...another no.

but......im little lost lately.....i have complete faith in Hashem because He carried me so far through many trials i wont mention all here...

but .....i told the Av Beit Din...i dont know what to do. i am not this right now and not that.

dont get me wrong im always kind to others...goyim or jews....but im a not a goy....i cant marry one....and im alone....facing this world....and even though up untill now i survived and i managed to do all it on my own. lately....the feeling of being alone is catching up with me...

i cant marry a jew...im not officially returned, every week i have to break shabbat and it hurts inside. i cant even socialize with people of the community. i am still an outsider.

the noahide community here...lets idol worshippers in...same with chabad. i suffered alot from the church leaving them. they didnt let me go gently.

i dont want anything to do with them....

so even noahides.......i pray every day if Hashem will send me my soulmate....because alone ....is horrible.

i just want someone that also wants to dedicate his life to Torah .....but i also have teens. who are not sure about what they want. they dont live with me. unfortunately ....long story but i see them and when they are old enough they want to come home. so i cant migrate either. i cant leave my children.

but...........should i even hope for a soulmate? should i even look? or is staying alone...better....i dont know anymore....

i am losing hope the rabbanim here will ever convert me. i learn from rabbanim abroad and they all say if i lived there...they would help me convert without questioning...

i am not converting for a man...im converting to serve Hashem with every minute of my life....im also human....i am a woman...i also want to find my soulmate....

but right now....i dont know what road Hashem wants me to go....

what if i lost my changes? im also 40....

in jewish dating terms....if i would start conversion now....by the time im done.....

i would be even older....in jewish dating terms....at age...

i have emunah...i know....but im human....times like this...i find my self fearing...maybe this is my life from now on.....

not here....nor there...

shavua tov and chodesh tov

a lost Bat Israel

Comment: Hello and welcome to Mi Yodeya. I'm a little confused by your story. You wrote that your mother's mother's mother's mother was Jewish, which means that your great-grandmother, grandmother, mother and you yourself are also Jewish. Why then are you trying to convert?

Comment: The beis din gave you their answer. Until you move to a Jewish community, you cannot join the Jewish people. What are we supposed to do? I mean, I can give you all the sympathy in the world but that's not going to help your situation. If you really want to join the Jewish people, there's no "easy street". You're going to have to uproot yourself. And I must say, I really don't recommend that for you. You're welcome to contact me thru the email in my profile as this "question" is likely to be closed.

Comment: If you have written evidence you are halachically Jewish, you do not need to convert.  I am not even sure you need rabbinical agreement that you are Jewish.

Comment: Hi Miriam, welcome to Mi Yodeya. If you need practical help with deciding to move and actually moving to a Jewish place, you may contact me at Davidariel25@gmail.com Much Success

Comment: Hi, it seems people here are very kind and helpful, however, if you would like an addition person to email, you can email me at liamkalson@gmail.com. I think I could give a couple small suggestions/observations.

Comment: Hi @Harel13 thank you for your response. even though we know from oral tradition she was jewish and intermarried. in order to return without full conversion , you will need a document that proves the women were jewish. think a brit mila of their full brothers or a death certificate that proofs they were burried according to jewish law. otherwise Rabbanim are not allowed to accept you as jewish. otherwise anyone could come in and claim so. but i dont have any problems with conversion. i gladly will convert.

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi problem is, is that we dont have proof on paper. only oral tradtion from living family members. and even if we did. because its several generations back and they women intermarried. even though they all had at least one daughter...ending with me. to remove all doubt..sometimes even in those cases a shorter conversion would take place. but i dont care to be honest, how long it takes. but im refused even to start learning with a Rabbi. so before you will convert , a potential convert will have to study halacha etc.

Comment: @ezra thank you for your answer and i know that i have to move. thats why im registered. there is only one problem. i asked several times the beit din and they never said that the moving part is the reason why they refuse. to be honest: that reason would make sense to me. because i know you cant live jewish without living in a jewish community. now, without going into that the rabbanim dont even live near the shul and they drive on shabbat.but when i asked if this was the problem...he said no. but when i asked what it was so i could work on it. i only got "if your situation changes"

Comment: @ezra and i know you mean well. but i WANT to uproot myself......but i can do all i can....and that is it. i am actively busy to move there. and i still will. i am not discouraged at all not to move closer. but what is my struggle is the being alone. but the Rabbanim is israel and america  are also very clear that they never heard people that really want to ignored. and keep in mind. im asking to start learning. not "hey i want to dive into the mikveh right now" i KNOW that learning alone will take years. only thing i got was "your life is complicated" but who's life is not??

Comment: @miriam in addition to the wonderful encouragement our members are giving you, and in addition to some of us offering our email connection, ... i see you feel you are simply being ignored for a potential conversion/acceptance process. If you wish, I would help you to connect with a valid Orthodox Bes Din for a conversion process. I have done so before with others. But of course, such a path is difficult for anyone. Again you may enquire at my email: Davidariel25@gmail.com No claims of 100% promises, just willing to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a very, very tough situation. You already know the answer to how get through this:  tefillah. Do not stop praying to Hashem. Feel free to ask Him for specific things you need - that's part of why we say the Borei Nefashot blessing.

On a practical level, you need to leave your current life behind and join a Jewish community. The best thing would be for you to come to Israel. But, if that's not practical for you right now, get involved with the Chabad community nearest to you. They may not be the exact flavor of Judaism you're looking for, but they're much better than nothing.